# Making node's fonts larger when using the qtree package

Tags: scaling, qtree

I'm using the `qtree` package in LaTeX, but the tree nodes have very small text. I'm also using `\scalebox` to scale down the tree since it does not fit in the page.

Is there a way to increase the size of the text while keeping the tree small? I tried `qtreeinithook` with `\Large` but without any luck, since the text is still not big enough.

Edit: so, the problem is related to the template I'm using from here ftp://ftp.cup.cam.ac.uk/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/tlp-cls/unpacked/tlp.cls

```
    \documentclass[conference]{tlp}
    \usepackage{qtree}
    \begin{document}
    \Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B !\qsetw{1cm} C ]
    \newcommand\qlabelhook{\Huge}
    \newcommand\qleafhook{\Huge}
    \Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B !\qsetw{1cm} C ]
    \end{document}
```

With this code, the edges of the tree get so big that the tree does not fit in the page. I guess the problem is with the template.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the `tlp` class redefines the `tabular` environment, which is used internally by `qtree`.  I've given a fix at the end but there's a simpler solution.

You can use use `tikz-qtree` instead of `qtree`.   The syntax is the same, although certain commands like `\qsetw` and `\qroof` are not supported (the former isn't needed, and the latter has an alternative syntax).  `tikz-qtree` doesn't seem to have the same issues with the class you're using:

```
\documentclass[conference]{tlp}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={font=\Large,anchor=base}]
\Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B  C ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**Solving the problem with `qtree`**

If you still need to use `qtree` you can add the following to your preamble, and then Gonzalo's solution works, but the first solution is clearly preferable.

```
\documentclass[conference]{tlp}
\usepackage{qtree}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\qshow@text}[3][c]{{#2{\begin{oldtabular}[t]
{@{\hskip\qtreepadding}#1@{\hskip\qtreepadding}}#3\end{oldtabular}}}}
\def\qroof#1.#2 {{%
\setbox\@qrscratchbox = \hbox{\let\qtreepadding=\qroofpadding
  \qshow@text[l]{\qleafhook}{#1}}%
\def\qtreepadding{0pt}%
\begin{oldtabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \setbox\@tempboxa = \hbox{\qshow@text{\qlabelhook}{#2}}%
      \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>0pt \box\@tempboxa \\ \fi
  \unitlength=\wd\@qrscratchbox \qdraw@roof \\[-0.6ex]
  \box\@qrscratchbox
\end{oldtabular}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B  C ]
    \newcommand\qlabelhook{\Huge}
    \newcommand\qleafhook{\Huge}
\Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B !\qsetw{1cm} C ]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\qleafhook` (for the leaves) and `\qlabelhook` (for non-terminal nodes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B !\qsetw{1cm} C ]

\newcommand\qlabelhook{\Huge}
\newcommand\qleafhook{\Huge}

\Tree [.A [ a b c d ].B !\qsetw{1cm} C ]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and it works, but somehow the template I am using messes up with everything and makes the edges of the tree **huge**.

Comment: @FlávioCruz: without some version of your actual code, it's almost impossible to detect the cause of the problem. If you want to, you can edit your question to add a minimal, complete version of your code illustrating the problem.